# Iterating through a loop and switching between two expressions that's only difference is the sign

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I return a method from another method. I am iterating through a loop and I need to switch between (y += x) and (y-= x) when a condition is true. I was thinking to declare a bool that when is true a method is called that returns (y += x) and when it is false (y+=x) is returned.

Can this possibly be done or are there a more elegant way to do this... code examples are appreciated. Thanks

Further explanation...
If the list contains e.g. 20 items. I loop through the list and do some stuff using (y -= x). If condition is true i need to continue to loop and do stuff but with (y+= x) this time until the condition is true again... and again reverting to (y-=x) and so on.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. When you say "return another method", a lot of people (including me) think that you want to return a reference to something that can be called. But you might want to call another method and return the results from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can return functions from functions. There is a number of types that define the signature of types. In your case, you would want a [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx) or more specifically `Func<int, int, int>`. For example, you could have an `Add` function, and a `Subtract` function like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> Add = (a, b) => a + b;
Func<int, int, int> Subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
```

If you then do your assignment, you can do `y = ThatFunction(x, y);` where `ThatFunction` would be a reference to whichever function you chose.

**However**, you asked for an elegant way, and this is definitely not an elegant way for the problem you are facing. Instead, you should just keep a boolean around that tells you which of those two actions you want to perform. And you can toggle that boolean whenever your condition is true:

```
bool subtract = false;
foreach (var someThing in someOtherThing)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // toggle the current action
        subtract = !subtract;
    }

    // do something else

    // now perform the correct action
    if (subtract)
        y -= x;
    else
        y += x;
}
```

As you can see, the `condition` is responsible for *toggling* the `subtract` boolean, but only the latter is resposible for choosing the correct action.

Comment: That's exactly what was in my mind (referring to the second answer) but I was not able to put it into practice. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. What you can do is return a Delegate - this is an object that contains a reference to a containing object and a method, and can be invoked.

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to call a method that returns another method to manipulate your state. Something like this should do it:

```
class NoIdeaWhatTheScenarioIs {
  private int y;
  private int x;

  void Add() { y += x; }
  void Sub() { y -= x; }

  Action GetAction(bool ifTrue) { if (ifTrue) { return Add; } else { return Sub; } }

  void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Thingie> things) {
    foreach(var thing in things) {
      GetAction(thing.condition)(); // <-- note the extra parens here
    }
  }
}
```

So GetAction returns a System.Action delegate, which is then immediately invoked.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean something like this. then yes it is possible

```
int MakeCalc(int result){
     if(result == 0)
          return MakeCalcForZero(result)
     return result /3;
}

int MakeCalcForZero(int result){
    return result +100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return a Func so you can execute against it.

```
Func<int, int, int> GetOperand(bool negate)
{
    if (negate)
        return (x, y) => { return y - x;};
    else
        return (x, y) => { return y + x; };
}
```

You can then call it using:

```
y = GetOperand(true).Invoke(x, y);
```